# Preencher valores nulos de uma coluna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tenho o seguinte df de exemplo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                               'Parrot', 'Parrot',
                               'Eagle', 'Eagle'],
                                'Max Speed': [380., 380., 24., None, 150., None]})

df

Animal  Max Speed
0   Falcon  380.0
1   Falcon  380.0
2   Parrot  24.0
3   Parrot  NaN
4   Eagle   150.0
5   Eagle   NaN
```

preciso substituir os valores nulos da coluna **Max Speed** com base na coluna **Animal**, neste caso ficaria assim:

```
df

Animal  Max Speed
0   Falcon  380.0
1   Falcon  380.0
2   Parrot  24.0
3   Parrot  24.0
4   Eagle   150.0
5   Eagle   150.0
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Para preencher os NaN use o método [.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Porém para o que você deseja, use o parâmetro `method="ffill"` (forward fill) conforme abaixo:

```
df.fillna(method="ffill")
```

Comment: Perfeito Paulo, muito obrigado!